# Differentiating Between Table Names

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have two tables that have the same column names;

```
APPLICATION_Reference.firstName, APPLICATION_Reference.lastName
APPLICATION_Recommendation.firstName, APPLICATION_Recommendation.lastName
```

```
$all_references = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *
FROM APPLICATION_Reference
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_Recommendation 
ON APPLICATION_Reference.referenceId = APPLICATION_Recommendation.referenceId
INNER JOIN Applicant ON APPLICATION_Reference.firstName = Applicant.givenName
ORDER BY APPLICATION_Reference.referenceId ASC");
```

And then I have an echo statement where I echo out my data: `$applicant_reference['firstName']`

My question is: **How do I differentiate between my different tables when echoing out the column names?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table aliases and column aliases.

In your query you can alias a whole table to make things more readable, e.g.

```
APPLICATION_Reference ref
```

Your query then becomes

```
SELECT *
FROM APPLICATION_Reference ref
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_Recommendation rec ref.referenceId = rec.referenceId
INNER JOIN Applicant app ON ref.firstName = app.givenName
ORDER BY ref.referenceId ASC
```

Instead of then using `SELECT *`, list the fields you are interested in and rename them to something that makes sense in your result set, e.g.

```
SELECT ref.firstName reference_first_name,
       rec.firstname recommendation_first_name,
       ...
```

You can then access the new column names in your PHP code. You certainly don't have to use such long references (e.g. `reference_first_name`) - those are just examples.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
SELECT *, table1.field AS field1, table2.field AS field2 ...
```

and then reference the fields as field1 and field2 in your output

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases

```
SELECT 
APPLICATION_Recommendation.lastName as APPLICATION_Recommendation_lastName,
Applicant .lastName as Applicant _lastName
... 
FROM APPLICATION_Reference
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_Recommendation ON APPLICATION_Reference.referenceId = APPLICATION_Recommendation.referenceId
INNER JOIN Applicant ON APPLICATION_Reference.firstName = Applicant.givenName
ORDER BY APPLICATION_Reference.referenceId ASC
```